# Facebook JS API: Any calls to FB.ui returns Error Code: 191

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, fb.ui

I'm dealing with this issue all day long. I checked my app settings, and I tried diferent ways and settings, but it's still not working. My app is in the Facebook canvas.

Any call to FB.ui, feed, apprequests, etc, returns me:

**API Error Code: 191

API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application

Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.**

I tried changing and passing the redirect_uri by many ways, but nothing happens...

ANY IDEA? THANKS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook API error 191](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure all of the details of your app, but I have seen this when your domain does not match your redirect url.

In my case I believe I just removed the domain from my facebook app settings.